# Prevent admins deleting other admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

This is a problem I haven't run into yet, but feel I will do.

Here's my Ability file:

```
user ||= User.create # create random name here

if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, User   
end
```

If Admins are simply User instances that have a role of `admin`. So won't this mean that admins will be able to delete other admins? How can I stop this happening and create a superadmin for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Try constraints like this,

```
if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, User, !has_role?(:admin)
end
```